# Why Am I getting Makefile:8: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I tried by adding the space tab before `cp` command till observing the same issue.
The go Makefile is as follow:
$cat Makefile

```
GOOS ?= $(shell go env GOOS)
TEMPLATE_PATH:= $(shell mktemp -d)
ifeq ($(GOARCH),amd64)
       TAG ?= -v1.10.1
       TAG_NONE ?=
endif

cp ./template/* $(TEMPLATE_PATH)
cd $(TEMPLATE_PATH) && sed -i.back "s|TAG|$(TAG)|g" deploy.yaml
cd $(TEMPLATE_PATH) && sed -i.back "s|TAG_NONE|$(TAG_NONE)|g" deploy.yaml

out/mybinary:
       echo "Hello!"
```

On running $ `make out/mybinary` command I get the error "Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop."

Comment: Did you read and apply all the other answers to exactly that problem?

Comment: I tried all other answers, I did have added the tab space still observed the same issue.

Comment: This question isn't really a duplicate of the other question linked here.  In this question, you don't even have a makefile at all: you have no rules defined, only recipes.  No amount of adding TABs will fix this...

Comment: I do have rules. I thought like too much info to the question. However just the make should work with message "make: *** No targets.  Stop.". Anyway editing question with rule.

Comment: Your cp and cd commands are not in any rule. You can't have commands outside rules.